# Delphi IDE - How to make disabled toolbar buttons grayscaled?

Tags: delphi, ide, toolbar

Seams like this one is for real Delphi geeks only.

This is how it looks (sorry, can't post images)
[Delphi IDE ugly toolbar](http://i.piccy.info/i4/da/ac/6e4748778dcfdc13ec5fede3a7e0.png)

[image]
<sub>(source: [piccy.info](http://i.piccy.info/i4/da/ac/6e4748778dcfdc13ec5fede3a7e0.png))</sub>

**What's wrong** - disabled Delphi IDE toolbar and menu buttons are ugly black/white images.
**What I want to do** - make them look gray-scaled.

**How?** I made some research. Main problem in virtual `TCustomImageList.DoDraw` method. When paramater `Enabled = False` it paints ugly things (see disabled buttons on screenshot). I created my own override for this function and it paints gray-scaled images when `Enabled = False`

Now I want to ***replace default `DoDraw` with my own*** in IDE (using design-time package):

1. I figured out that unit ImgList is compiled-in bds.exe, so trick with patching this function in `rtlXXX.bpl` will not work.
2. Searching for function's body content gave no result. Looks like bds.exe's implementation (I'm talikng about machine codes) of `DoDraw` is a bit different.

Any suggestions or ideas of how can I make this possible? As base example of runtime code patching I took Andy's Midas Speed Fix: `FindMethodPtr`, `HookProc`, `UnhookProc`

Comment: Let me make things a little clearer - I want to fix IDE, not applications I make using it

Comment: Why do you care how the IDE draws it's disabled toolbuttons? You can tell they're disabled, and that should be all that matters. Also, instead of trying to hack the IDE yourself, post a bug report or feature request in CodeGear's Quality Central, so that the developers who maintain the IDE can possibly change things in a future release.

Comment: I was trying to get some experience here. I don't want to prove CodeGear/Embarcadero that gray-scaled are better and wait for them to implement this feature.

Comment: If you make your disabled icons grayscaled, you may end up with invisible (or difficult to see) icons - some colors converted to grayscale may show up as the same grey color as the background (toolbar itself). I think this is the point guys from Delphi do it in this way...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made it :) Thanks to everyone who participated or viewed this question!

This is how my IDE looks now:
[Fixed toolbar http://blog.frantic.im/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/delphi-ide-after.PNG](http://blog.frantic.im/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/delphi-ide-after.PNG)

I just messed up with `vclXXX.pbl`, my fault. Sources can be found [here](http://blog.frantic.im/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/NiceToolbar-src.zip). Gradient toolbars must be enabled to make it work. If you are interested in further development of this idea - read [this](http://blog.frantic.im/dev/delphi/delphi-toolbar/) topic

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm understanding the problem badly but if you just want to override the DoDraw function why don't you just create your own component that inherits from TCustomImageList, override the desired function so that it does what you want and register it into the IDE?

Comment: ...and this will give all my applications new look-and-feel, but I want to make changes to RAD Studio IDE itself. How can I replace IDE's default ImageList with my own?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make your own overriden components, you can change the realization directly in *[DelphiPath]\source\Win32\vcl\ImgList.pas*.

But it is really not a good way.

Answer (score 0):

I've always disliked the way Delphi creates default disabled images from enabled one. This not only manifests itself in the IDE, but it does persist down to the application you're developing. The disabled images in your application look just as bad.

I have in the past tried to figure out what Delphi did to derive the disabled images and build on that. But it still is on my "things to do" list to finish that off.

None-the-less, these are some articles about the Delphi "glitch" that I encountered quite a while ago that may or may not help you:

1. [Indistinguishable gray blobs in disabled menu items, by Vladimir S.](http://www.latiumsoftware.com/en/delphi/00042.php3)
2. [MenuImgList.pas](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en&sa=N&cd=1&ct=rc#Yx3HDuBVDL4/MenuImgList.pas&q=menuimglist)
3. [Fixing a Buttons Drawing Glitch in Delphi 5](http://web.archive.org/web/20021107230424/http://undu.com/Articles/010323b.html)
4. [Fixing a Menu Drawing Glitch in Delphi 4](http://web.archive.org/web/20021110120011/http://www.undu.com/Articles/980731a.html)

Comment: @lkessler: You missed the OP's comment to his own question, where he indicated he wanted to fix the IDE's toolbar, not one in his own application.

Comment: So I did. In my excitement of finally seeing someone address the gray blob problem, I overlooked he was talking about the IDE. Even so, I'll update my answer and address his question. Thanks.